# difference in DataBases

Tags: mysql

How to make query to information_schema.tables to get list of available tables which is exist in one DB but not exist in another one, something like diff but more suitable. I just need sql query.

So i have Db's like A,B,C,D and all these DB's should has the same tables, how I can check it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables
group by table_name
having count(table_schema) < 4
```

if you have 4 DB's. If more you have to adjust the `having` clause.

Answer (score 1):

This query give you all unique tables in all databases.

```
    SELECT *,count(TABLE_NAME) 
    FROM 
   `TABLES` group by table_name 
    having count(TABLE_NAME)=1
```

And if you want repeated table names then use this

```
    SELECT *,count(TABLE_NAME) 
    FROM 
   `TABLES` group by table_name 
    having count(TABLE_NAME)>1
```